# How to get form value of <ul> in golang?

Tags: html, forms, go, html-lists

In my use case I am using tag [tag-it](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it) to get tags from user. I am getting the tags input in html `<ul>` form. I am using golang in server side.

html:

```
   <form class="comment-form" action="/add/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-input">
      <label for="tags_label">Tags</label>
      <ul id="tags">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $("#myTags").tagit();
          var tagsArray = ["C", "C++", "Go", "Ruby"];
          $("#tags").tagit({
              itemName: "teamId",
              fieldName: "teamName",
              availableTags: tagsArray,
              allowSpaces:true,
              caseSensitive:false,
              removeConfirmation:true,
              placeholderText:"Tags",
              tagLimit: 5,
              allowDuplicates: false,
              singleFieldDelimiter: ',',
              onlyAvailableTags: false
          });
        </script>
      </ul>
    </div>
   </form>
```

and in server end I am trying to get the value like below similar to other fields in the form,

```
tags            := r.FormValue("tags")
log.Printf("Tags : ", tags)
```

But it is not working.  Could someone help me with this?

**EDIT:**
When I inspect the element this is what I see,

```
<div class="form-input">
    <label for="tags_label">Tags</label>
    <ul id="tags" class="tagit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#myTags").tagit();
            var tagsArray = ["C", "C++", "Go", "Ruby"];
            $("#tags").tagit({
                    itemName: "teamId",
                    fieldName: "teamName",
                    availableTags: tagsArray,
                    allowSpaces:true,
                    caseSensitive:false,
                    removeConfirmation:true,
                    placeholderText:"Tags",
                    tagLimit: 5,
                    allowDuplicates: false,
                    singleFieldDelimiter: ',',
                    onlyAvailableTags: false
            });
        </script><li class="tagit-new"><input type="text" class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="Tags" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"></li>
    </ul>                                            
</div>
```

Comment: `r.FormValue` expects a HTML form value. I don't see a `<form>` tag in your HTML.

Comment: @PepijnvanLeeuwen - I updated with the form. This is the part of the large form, so I missed to add it before

Comment: It seems that the jQuery plugin adds a hidden input type, i.e. `<input type="hidden" value="testvalue" name="tags" class="tagit-hidden-field">`. Use 'Inspect element' to verify that the `name` attribute matches your Go code. Examples I used: https://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html

Comment: @PepijnvanLeeuwen - I updated the question with inspect element output. But I dont see any hidden field :(

Comment: Remove `itemName: "teamId",` from the options and in Go, see if you get a value by using `r.FormValue("teamName")`. If that doesn't work, remove all options but `fieldName` and `availableTags`. More info about options: https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it#options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem: you expected a single field but you didn't specify it in the [options](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it#options) of `tag-it`. Use it as following (added some comments for clarity):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myTags").tagit();
    var tagsArray = ["C", "C++", "Go", "Ruby"];
    $("#tags").tagit({
        fieldName: "teamName", // The name of the hidden input field
        availableTags: tagsArray,
        allowSpaces:true,
        caseSensitive:false,
        removeConfirmation:true,
        placeholderText:"Tags",
        tagLimit: 5,
        allowDuplicates: false,
        singleField: true, // Use a hidden input element with the fieldName name
        singleFieldDelimiter: ',', // Optional, default value is same.
        onlyAvailableTags: false
    });
</script>
```

During runtime (and entering tags) a hidden `<input>` will be used, with the tag that you specified in the `tag-it` options.

```
<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="Go,another value,C" name="teamName">
```

In Go, handle it as following (you missed the `%s` in `Printf`):

```
tags := r.FormValue("teamName")
log.Printf("Tags: %s", tags)
```

You can then split the tags with [`strings.Split`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split).